# AngularJS directive to run after text input changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I am using a bootstrap calendar datepicker that operates and modifies an `<input type="text">` element.

If I use `ng-change="myAngularExpression()"` it calls the function as soon as the text box is clicked. How can I have the function call *after* the input actually changes?

In my specific case, a user clicks in the text box that is displaying MM/DD/YYYY and a dropdown calendar comes down, then the angular expression executes, then the user changes the value and nothing happens until they click off the element and back on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using a jQuery-based Bootstrap datepicker. Unfortunately, mixing jQuery-based Bootstrap widgets with Angular rarely works out well.

The better alternative is to use [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), which is a collection of Bootstrap widgets written entirely in Angular. For example, here's a [datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

Once you're using Angular for your widgets (with UI Bootstrap), watching for changes to your date becomes as simple as `$scope.$watch()`:

```
$scope.$watch('date', function() { /* ... */ });
```

Full example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  
  // watch date for changes
  $scope.$watch('date', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue)
    {
      $scope.message = 'Date changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Main">  
    <datepicker ng-model="date"></datepicker>
    <div ng-bind="message"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Someone may be able to provide an answer that allows the jQuery-based datepicker to work "good enough" with Angular, but that's a slippery road.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to do some manipulating, but it looks like this will work. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, I know it's not ideal in the short-term, but it'll be worth it in the long-term.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ng-keydown` ? This way the input will change only when you press your key down on it.

```
<input ng-keydown='someAwesomeMethodHere()'/>
```